# Show that $(1+\sqrt{3})^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt{3}$ for integers $a_n$ and $b_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Prove that for every natural number $n$, $(1+\sqrt{3})^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt{3}$, where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are natural numbers.

Comment: Induction comes to mind.

Comment: For the induction step, suppose that for some $k$ we have $(1+\sqrt{3})^k=a_k+b_k\sqrt{3}$, where $a_k$ and $b_k$ are integers. Then $(1+\sqrt{3})^{k+1}=(1+\sqrt{3})^k(1+\sqrt{3})=(a_k+b_k\sqrt{3})(1+\sqrt{3})=(a_k+3b_k)+(a_k+b_k)\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Note there is a typo above, towards the end, that I can't get rid of, $a\,k$ instead of $a_k$.

Comment: Andre: You should have made this an answer, not a comment. You can then always edit it and you will usually get more points.

Answer (score 2):

$$
(1+\sqrt{3})^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \pmatrix{n \\ k} 1^{n-k} (\sqrt{3})^k = \sum_{k =even} \pmatrix{n \\ k}(\sqrt{3})^k + \sum_{k=odd}\pmatrix{n \\ k}(\sqrt{3})^k = a_n + b_n \sqrt{3}
$$